# Plotlyjs reactive image

Tags: javascript, html, plotly

For my code below, I want to keep the image in `Plotly.toImage` but only change the layout coordinates. It will have a white square in the middle that changes based on the eventdata or in other words

```
  layout.shapes[0].x0 = eventdata["xaxis.range[0]"];
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any help?

```
var img_jpg = d3.select('#jpg-export');

var img_png = d3.select('#png-export');
var svg  = d3.select('#svg-export');
var redi = Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
redi.then( function(gd) {
    Plotly.toImage(gd,{height:700,width:700})
    .then( function(url) {
        img_jpg.attr("src", url);
        Plotly.toImage(gd,{format:'jpeg',height:700,width:700});
    })
});

myDiv.on('plotly_relayout', function(eventdata){  
    console.log( eventdata["xaxis.range[0]"]);
    console.log(layout.shapes[0]);
     // layout.shapes[0].x0=eventdata["xaxis.range[0]"];
     // layout.shapes[0].x1=eventdata["xaxis.range[1]"];

Plotly.toImage(redi,{height:700,width:700})
.then( function(url) {
     img_jpg.attr("src", url);
     Plotly.toImage(redi,{format:'jpeg',height:700 ,width:700});
});
console.log("changes!");
```

Comment: There's not enough closing brackets in your code so if this issue is still of interest, please correct that